# float is not coma seperated in german locale in perl

Tags: linux, perl, locale, setlocale

I have installed a linux machine on german locale. When I print the float/double in perl, I am expecting it to be printed in coma seperated instead of dot separated. But it is not happening. Any idea ?

```
    [root@IDCDVAM886 ~]# uname -a
    Linux IDCDVAM886 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 29 17:29:29 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    [root@IDCDVAM886 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)
    [root@IDCDVAM886 ~]# locale
    LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
    LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
    LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
    LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
    LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
    LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
    LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
    LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
    LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
    LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
    LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
    LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
    LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
    LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
    [root@IDCDVAM886 ~]# echo $LC_ALL
    de_DE.UTF-8
    [root@IDCDVAM886 ~]# echo $LC_NUMERIC
    de_DE.UTF-8

    [root@IDCDVAM886 ~]# cat my.pl 
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    use locale;

    print "LC_NUMERIC = $ENV{LC_NUMERIC}\n";
    print 5/2 ;
    print "\n";
    my $val = 2,5;
    print "$val\n";

[root@IDCDVAM886 ~]# ./my.pl 
LC_NUMERIC = de_DE.UTF-8
2.5
2
```

Comment: Your assignment `$val = 2,5` will only assign `2`. The `,` doesn't magically become the decimal point character in Perl because of your locale. It's still a list constructor, so you're really assigning the list `(2, 5)` to `$val`, but because there is only the one scalar on the left, the second element of the list gets discarded. That's why you see the `2` in the last line of the output.

Comment: ',' is a decimal point character in perl when the locale is de_DE.UTF-8. To be more specific when LC_NUMERIC is de.DE.UTF-8. Please refer to "http://perldoc.perl.org/perllocale.html" Section "Category LC_NUMERIC : Numeric Formatting" @simbabque

Comment: That's for automatic conversion of strings to numbers in the output. As [ceving's answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40738719/1331451) and the discussion on it explain, it's not possible to change the grammar of the language that way. It's an operator. I'm from Germany and I have to deal with a lot of commas in places where internationally they don't make sense. A lot of legacy code I've worked with would have been way worse if what you suggesting was possible.

Answer (score 7):

Your question addresses two different topics. The following assumes that you unset `LC_ALL` and set `LC_NUMERIC`, because `LC_ALL` overrides `LC_NUMERIC`.

```
 $ unset LC_ALL
 $ export LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
```

**Localization of the programming language**

> ```
> $ perl -e 'printf "%f\n", 2,5'
> 2.000000
> ```

Your locale defines the way how numbers are printed. The locale does not change the grammar of the programming language. Perl code is indifferent to changes of the locale. If it would not be, you have to modify every single program for every single language. This would be real pain as it is in Excel for example.

**Localization of the input and output of a program**

> ```
> $ perl -e 'printf "%f\n", "2,5"'
> 2.000000
> ```

This can be considered a bug. Bash does it right:

```
$ printf '%f\n' 2,5
2,500000
```

In order to get it right with Perl 5.18.2, I have to do:

```
$ export LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
$ perl -e 'use locale; use POSIX qw(locale_h); setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE"); printf "%f\n", "2,5"'
2,500000
```

Even if I use `setlocale` without setting `LC_ALL` I get the wrong result in Perl 5.18.2. This is nuts.

But Perl has a long tradition of being clumsy when it comes to localization. Latin1 in the source file was a similar debacle.

Comment: It would also prevent `,` from being used as an operator. e.g. `f(2,5)` might pass one or two arguments based on locale.

Comment: ',' is a decimal point character in perl when the locale is de_DE.UTF-8. To be more specific when LC_NUMERIC is de.DE.UTF-8. Please refer to "perldoc.perl.org/perllocale.html"; Section "Category LC_NUMERIC : Numeric Formatting" @Ceving

Comment: @ikegami: comments above

Comment: I have seen many german customers use this way of programming it works perfectly when we use 'use locale' and setlocale to set the german locale.

Comment: @SrikanthGanesan how would you make a list of numbers then? Consider the following German sentence: _Diese Liste enthaelt die Zahlen 2,5, 3,142, 25, 26, 33,33333 und 23,0._ That's hard to read, but possible because humans are mostly smart. We understand context. But computers are not. Perl doesn't care about the spaces much and cannot know which commas are list separators and which ones are decimal points.

Comment: @Srikanth Ganesan, Actually, it's you who should read the [doc you linked](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllocale.html#Category-LC_NUMERIC%3a-Numeric-Formatting). As you can see, there's no mention of `use locale;` affecting the syntax of numeric literals.